# How can i add bootstrap 4 scss in slate theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, shopify, slate

I am creating Shopify theme using slate, I want to add bootstrap 4 SCSS in my theme
I have tried this by adding bootstrap's SCSS folder in `styles/vendor/bootstrap` folder and import it in `theme.scss`

```
/*================ BOOTSTRAP ================*/
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss');
```

the issue is that after including this `slate build` successfully done but it gives an error in the console

```
 Refused to apply style from 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2331/3377/t/10/assets/theme.scss.css?9739733336988663236' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

and when I open CSS it shows

```
Failed to compile SCSS file
```

Can anyone have the solution for this? or any other method for import bootstrap 4 in slate theme

Comment: Can you consider disabling the strict MIME checking?

Comment: I don't know how to disable the strict MIME checking

Comment: As a work around, you may include this scss file (https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2331/3377/t/10/assets/theme.scss) or this css file (https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2331/3377/t/10/assets/theme.scss.css) directly in your vendor folder.

Comment: It's not working

Answer (score 1):

`@import` is not supported by **Shopify** in SASS files.
You must load your file separately in **Theme.liquid** layout.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to @import each file using the url() method since Slate can't parse normal sass file imports. Don't forget that this applies to all the mixins and utilities that Bootstrap includes using this method as well.

**Short Answer**

Copy the imports from bootstrap.scss, mixins.scss and utilities.scss to /your-theme-root/src/styles/theme.scss and adjust the import syntax and paths.

**Example**

The following example assumes that you have copied the entire contents of bootstrap/scss to /your-theme-root/src/styles/vendor/bootstrap rather than including the entire Bootstrap repository -- you will need to insert /scss/ for the following to work with your current paths.

Change this:

```
/*================ BOOTSTRAP ================*/
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss');
```

To this:

```
/*================ Bootstrap 4 ================*/

@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_functions.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_variables.scss');

/* == MIXINS :: direct import
 * @import url('vendor/bootstrap/_mixins.scss');
 */
    // Utilities
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_breakpoints.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_hover.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_image.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_badge.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_resize.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_screen-reader.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_size.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_reset-text.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_text-emphasis.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_text-hide.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_text-truncate.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_visibility.scss');

    // // Components
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_alert.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_buttons.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_caret.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_pagination.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_lists.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_list-group.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_nav-divider.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_forms.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_table-row.scss');

    // // Skins
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_background-variant.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_border-radius.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_box-shadow.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_gradients.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_transition.scss');

    // // Layout
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_clearfix.scss');
    // @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_navbar-align.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_grid-framework.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_grid.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/mixins/_float.scss');

@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_root.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_reboot.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_type.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_images.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/code.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_grid.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_tables.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_forms.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_buttons.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_transitions.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_dropdown.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_button-group.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_input-group.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_custom-forms.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_nav.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_navbar.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_card.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_breadcrumb.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_pagination.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_badge.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_jumbotron.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_alert.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_progress.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_media.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_list-group.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_close.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_modal.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_tooltip.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_popover.scss');
@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_carousel.scss');

/* == MIXINS :: direct import
 * @import url('vendor/bootstrap/_utilities.scss');
 */
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/utilities/_align.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/utilities/_background.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/utilities/_borders.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/utilities/_clearfix.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/utilities/_display.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/utilities/_embed.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/utilities/_flex.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/utilities/_float.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/utilities/_position.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/utilities/_screenreaders.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/utilities/_sizing.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/utilities/_spacing.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/utilities/_text.scss');
    @import url('vendor/bootstrap/utilities/_visibility.scss');

@import url('vendor/bootstrap/_print.scss');
```

Comment: I already tried this it compiles successfully but after upload when I open my store, no CSS apply in theme and in the console it gives  MIME type error as I mentioned in my question